# Solving an equation of complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis

prove that $8z^4-6z+5=0$ has one root in each quadrant. How shall i start thinking about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we set $z=w/2$, we can consider $w^4-6w+10=0$, which is simpler and scaling by a positive real factor doesn't change the quadrant where a complex number lives in.

So I'll consider the equation $z^4-6z+10=0$.

First of all, the equation has no real roots; indeed, the real function
$$
f(x)=x^4-6x+10
$$
has derivative $f'(x)=4x^3-6$ that vanishes at $\sqrt[3]{3/2}$ and
$$
f(\sqrt[3]{3/2})
=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}}-6\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}}+10
=10-\frac{9}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}}>0
$$
Thus the complex roots are in conjugate pairs, say
$$
z_1=a+ib,\quad z_2=a-ib,\quad
z_3=c+id,\quad z_3=c-id
$$
where we can assume $b>0$ and $d>0$. The sum of the roots is $0$, so
$$
2a+2c=0
$$
and therefore one among $a$ and $c$ is positive and the other one is negative, unless they're both zero. However the equation has no purely imaginary roots, so $a\ne0$ and $c\ne0$.